# Number theoretic partial differential equation

Tags: number-theory, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Consider the equation

$$t\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Phi_n(x,t)=-x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Phi_n(x,t)+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\Lambda(n)\Phi_n(x,t)$$

where $\Lambda(n)$ represents an arbitrary number theoretic function, that is a function $\Lambda:\Bbb N \to \Bbb C.$ So far I've solved it for $\Lambda(n)=2T_n$ for $T_n$ the triangular numbers. That is I found a $\Phi$ and a $\Lambda$ which satisfies the relation. See also [this related question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4751932/460999).

> Is there a name for PDE's like this? Are there any resources that discuss PDE's involving number theoretic functions?

Comment: Are there reasons for not considering, instead, $t(\partial^2/\partial t^2)\Phi_n(x,t) = -x(\partial/\partial x)\Phi_n(x,t) + \Lambda(n)\Phi_n(x,t)$? And what do you see the domain and boundary conditions being?

Comment: @Aruralreader I see the domain being $D= \bigg\lbrace \Bbb R^2_{\gt 0}-\lbrace x,\Phi \ne 1  \rbrace :t>0 \bigg\rbrace$ where $x,\Phi=1$ is the boundary. And I would like hyperbolic initial conditions i.e. Cauchy data: $\Phi_t(x)|_{t=0}.$